# Automatically Granting GitHub Actions Workflow Access to Organization-Level Secrets/Variables Based on Repository Naming Convention

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm currently managing an organization on GitHub and have set up organization-level secrets and variables that I want to use in GitHub Actions workflows across multiple repositories. Rather than manually granting access to each repository, I'm looking for an automated approach based on a repository naming convention.

**Issue**

I have organization-level secrets and variables that need to be accessed by repositories with names following a specific pattern. For example, I want all repositories with names starting with "YY-Something-" to have automatic access to these secrets and variables.

Desired Solution:

I'm seeking guidance on how to create a streamlined and scalable solution. Ideally, I want to set up a workflow that dynamically grants access to organization-level secrets and variables for all repositories that match a specified naming convention.

I've explored creating a GitHub Actions workflow in a centralized repository, but I'm facing challenges in dynamically determining repository names and providing access based on a naming convention.

Or, just select all the repos that have that specified naming convention... Any tips?